# Can I order my CSS columns horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout, column-count

Here is my code:

```css
.column {
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner">2</div>
    <div class="inner">3</div>
    <div class="inner">4</div>
    <div class="inner">5</div>
    <div class="inner">6</div>
    <div class="inner">7</div>
    <div class="inner">8</div>
    <div class="inner">9</div>
    <div class="inner">10</div>
    <div class="inner">11</div>
    <div class="inner">12</div>
</div>
```

The result is: 
1    4    7    10 
2    5    8    11 
3    6    9    12

What I want is: 
1    2    3    4 
5    6    7    8 
9    10   11   12

Is that possible? How should I make it?

Comment: This post might be somewhat helpful: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/23914/re-arrange-default-column-order-css3-columns/

Comment: This really helpful actually

Comment: The link is dead, any chance you have an offline version of it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is even easier:

```css
.inner:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
}

.inner {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner">2</div>
    <div class="inner">3</div>
    <div class="inner">4</div>
    <div class="inner">5</div>
    <div class="inner">6</div>
    <div class="inner">7</div>
    <div class="inner">8</div>
    <div class="inner">9</div>
    <div class="inner">10</div>
    <div class="inner">11</div>
    <div class="inner">12</div>
</div>
```

You can apply `float: left` and clear `float: left` every 4n+1 elements.

**Ref:**

[**:nth-child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: I found this solution applied nicely also to a long `<ul>` that I needed to display in two horizontal columns.

Comment: This is okay but it doesn't allow for different height elements.

Comment: Love this solution. Any way of allowing different height?

Comment: I couldn't make this work with `<ul>` - does it need some extra work, and what do you need to apply to `<ul>` and `<li>` respectively?

Comment: Also I think this solution is not very friendly to responsive design. If say you choose 4 columns, but then you make the browser window less wide to only fit 3 or 2 columns, then items will be misaligned and you'll have gaps with no items. Which makes sense, since what then physically fits on the screen no longer matches the `(4n+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Mansonry.js is the solution. Check this out http://masonry.desandro.com/
Also check out this demo. This is what you need i guess.. I am also trying to implement such thing :)
http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index2.html

As far as I know there's no way to do this with CSS only which is sad

Answer (score 0):

I actually put some effort forward this time.  ignore everything from previous edit

[the display property's inline-blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4281120/2502012) is probably what you want to use.

[Here](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) is a thorough guide on how to use it

And here's a brief demo

```
li {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @CallMeAhLun You dont think that it would work or that a better solution exists? The former seems more likely which makes me sad

Comment: I looking for a better solution and the answer you gave me isn't a better solution. I need work in CMS, I need it in dynamic.

Comment: @CallMeAhLun well you should have mentioned that i'll do some research for ya

Comment: @CallMeAhLun there ya go, thats a real answer this time

Comment: that is the different thing I want.

Answer (score -1):

check my simple codes below url.
https://github.com/JJ81/column-count
maybe you can have what you want.

Comment: It's good to include the relevant code in your answer as links aren't future proof.

Answer (score -2):

Apply this:

```
.column { 
  width: 100px; 
  overflow:hidden;
} 
.column .inner {
  width:  20px; 
  float:left; 
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: could you explain in the body of your answer?