# Spacing a list in columns in HTML?

Tags: html

I've created a `<ul>` and `<li>` list and got a ton of different information in it. Is it possible to space different pieces of information in one `<li>` over the page, like it had columns?

Like the first word of `<li>` is aligned at the left side of the page, then the second is always at the first 1/4 the 3rd at half and the 4th at 3/4, for every `<li>`?

Is this possible, if yes, how is it done? If needed I can post my PHP/HTML Code in here (though it's dynamic).

EDIT: Here is the Code: http://jsfiddle.net/woz1r55e/ :)

Thanks beforehand already :)

Comment: Please post a testable, working version of your code in a jsfiddle. In your case you use php to generate your html. Please generate the html and put the output in a fiddle. That way people see what you mean. Now it's just a guessing game.

Comment: Will do now (just wanted suggestions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS define two classes

```
.inline-block
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.col
{
    width: 25%;
}
```

and then define  containers for whatever you want in those columns.

```
<div>
    <div class="inline-block col">List 1
        </div>List 2<div class="inline-block col">
        </div>List 3<div class="inline-block col">
        </div>List 4<div class="inline-block col">
    </div>
</div>
```

Source: [4 column CSS layout - Fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281018/4-column-css-layout-fluid)

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, this could actually solve OPs problem if implemented correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/woz1r55e/1/

I added this css:

```
ul ul ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
}
```

I'd recommend giving either the `<li>` a class to make it inline block or to give the third `<ul>` class and make it's children inline-block

Answer (score -2):

Create different css classes for each "column":

```
ul.Col1 { margin-left: 10px; }
ul.Col2 { margin-left: 210px; }
ul.Col3 { margin-left: 410px; }

<ul class="Col1">
   ...
</ul>
etc...
```